# Having a field of JSON dictionary on input type for mutation

Tags: c#, graphql, graphql-dotnet

I am trying to create a mutation that takes an input type `FooInputType`. My problem is having a field on that input to represent a JSON dictionary(string-string). for example, `foo.tags` field could have any set of key-value pairs of type string.

sample mutation:

```
{
  "query": "mutation ($foo: FooInputType) { addFoo(foo: $foo) { tags } }",
  "variables": {
    "foo": { "bar": "test", "tags": { "priority": "high" } }
  }
}
```

Here is the mutation:

```
class MyMutation : ObjectGraphType {
    public MyMutation() {
        Field<TaskItemType>("addFoo", "Add a new foo",
            new QueryArgument<FooInputType> {Name = "foo"}
        );
    }
}
```

And input type:

```
class FooInputType : InputObjectGraphType {
    public FooInputType() {
        Field<StringGraphType>("bar");
        Field<InputObjectGraphType<JObject>>("tags");
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I think having a schema-less JSON field is not possible in GraphQL anyways :/